# Narrator narrating UI element with `isTabStop=false`

Tags: xaml, uwp, accessibility, uwp-xaml, narrator

I have one xaml page where there are multiple UI elements are there, and i wanted narrator to pick some UI element and ignore other. So with below code you can, see that I have four Grid Row Definition the last UI element is rendered on screen as `Grid.RowSpan=4` and other UI elements also got intialized just for performance reason, but it won't be visible intially untill the last element Visibility will be set to `Collapsed`.

What i want when that "UserControlView1" control is rendered narrator should not pick other UI element, but once that is gone then narrator should start picking those UI element.

I have tried `IsTabStop=false` but not sure why it is not working.

```xml
<Page
    xmlns:mvvm="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
    mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    // some random namespaces declaration
    Loaded="PageLoaded">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               // some Grid Column definition
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               // "4" Grid Row definition...
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ctl:UserControlView2
               x:Name="UserControlView2"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                IsTabStop="False"/>

            <ctl:UserControlView3
                x:Name="UserControlView2"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                IsTabStop="False" --> I have set IsTabStop to false />

            <ctl:UserControlView4
                x:Name="UserControlView3"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                IsTabStop="False" --> I have set IsTabStop to false />

            <ctl:UserControlView1
                d:Visibility="Collapsed"
                x:Name="UserControlView1"
                x:Load="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserControlView1}"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="4" // as it span to four rows the reason being its gets render at top of the screen and other UI element will be there beneath it.
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                TabIndex="0"/>
        </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: `IsTabStop` would prevent the keyboard focus from moving to that element but does not prevent a screen reader, such as narrator, from being able to access that element. You'd need to hide it from the screen reader. I'm not an XAML coder so didn't want to post an official answer but I found info about [Visibility.Collapsed and Visibility.Hidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-1), which is analogous to CSS `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`, respectively, and hides the content from screen readers.

Comment: thanks, for commenting that, but if we hide that element, when i need to make it visible, it will do all the initialization at that time and hit performance issue i guess.

Comment: I made a test with `Button`, after the `IsTabStop` property is set to false, the Narrator will not read the Buttons anymore. I'm not sure if this is because you are using a `usercontrol`

Comment: I found one other way to resolve this issue, i used "IsEnabled" property instead of "Visibility" as "IsEnabled" will keep it disabled and narrator will not pick up but also in background it will allow to initialize the things as well so won't be that much of performance hit.
@RoyLi-MSFT